# What is the fate of an accepted paper in Springer conference but not being presented?

Tags: publications

I have sent a paper to a conference whose proceedings are published in Springer and that paper got accepted there. But I am not able to attend the conference. Then what would be its fate? Does that come into digital library? Second, do conference proceedings contain my paper? Third, will this publication count as a valid publication?

Comment: That depends on the conference policy, at least mostly.

Comment: In many cases the paper would not be published unless it was actually presented at the conference.  You should contact the program chair of the conference (and/or the editor of the proceedings volume if that's a different person) and ask.

Comment: Have you registered (paid) for the conference? The first rule is: No registration => your paper does nor appear in the proceedings

Answer (score 2):

The comments above are the answers you want. I am just reiterating them here because I think the question deserves an answer. If they accepted your paper, it means the conference organizers think it's interesting. You should mention to them your inability to attend, and if you can't for any reason publish it elsewhere, you could ask them if they are willing to review your contribution and publish it. 
Conference organizers often serve as editors of the conference proceedings, so it's entirely up to them to publish it anyway, or not. And they typically do not have any special incentive to go one way or another, so do try!

Comment: Another reason to contact the conference organizers is to stay off a black list that may inofficially be kept about conference no-shows.